# Sort array by highest key=>value

Tags: php, arrays

I want to sort an array highest to lowest by the value of `amount`. My array `$res` is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [id] => 1
    [1] => Testowy 1
    [user] => Testowy 1
    [2] => 150
    [amount] => 150
    [3] => 1,2,3
    [what] => 1,2,3
    [4] => Polska
    [country] => Polska
    [5] => 1
    [platform] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [id] => 2
    [1] => Testowy 2
    [user] => Testowy 2
    [2] => 100
    [amount] => 100
    [3] => 1
    [what] => 1
    [4] => United States
    [country] => United States
    [5] => 2
    [platform] => 2
)
```

I tried using `max` and `arsort`, but none of those seem to accept which key they should use for sorting. Any help?

Comment: [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)?

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but if this result is the result of a db query, you could also sort in the query by using e.g. ORDER BY

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: all basic ways to sort arrays and data in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Try usort

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return ($a["amount"]<=$b["amount"])?-1:1;
}

usort($array, "cmp");
```

Comment: Maybe dont use strcmp, but a simple '>' cause amount is no string at all. Maybe wrong for sorting '1 and 10'.

Comment: Now you are missing the equal case :) `return ($a["amount"]>=$b["amount"])` (`>=` or `<=` depending on the sorting order) will be enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
usort($res, function ($a, $b){
    return $b['amount'] - $a['amount'];
});
print_r($res);
```

For versions of PHP < 5.3, use the following:

```
function cmp($a, $b){
    return $b['amount'] - $a['amount'];
}
usort($res, "cmp");
```

Comment: I tried `usort`, but I'm getting `usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given`. `$res` is from `while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query))`.

Comment: Isn't `mysql_fetch_array` returning array?

Comment: @TomekBuszewski - It should be, but you wouldn't be getting an error like that unless you were trying to feed `usort` a boolean value. Why don't you try dumping `$res` to see what you get.

Comment: I used `print_r($res)` and I pasted it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use sorting functions with user defined comparators, like: usort:

http://php.net/usort

Then your comparator gets two objects and tells (by any logic you want) which one is greater):

```
function compare($a, $b) {
    $result = -1;
    if( $a["amount"] == $b["amount"]) {
      $result = 0;
    } else {
       if( $a["amount"] > $b["amount"] ) {
          $result = 1;
       }
    }

    return $result;
}

usort($res, "compare");
```

Comment: is the `1` in `$a1`->`($a1, $b)` a typo?

Comment: Overkill. Simplest function Body: `return ($a["amount"]>=$b["amount"])` (`>=` or `<=` depending on the sorting order) (or the substraction Version of Pe de Leao)

Comment: @dognose: nope. it's answer for newbie for him to understand. No place for tricks

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, I know it is very late please don't mind

```
$data = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'user' => 'Testowy 1',
        'amount' => 100,
        'what' => '1,2,3',
        'country' => 'Polska',
        'platform' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'user' => 'Testowy 2',
        'amount' => 130,
        'what' => '1',
        'country' => 'United States',
        'platform' => 2,
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'user' => 'Testowy 3',
        'amount' => 180,
        'what' => '1',
        'country' => 'United States',
        'platform' => 2,
    ],
];

usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    $aValue = $a['amount'];
    $bValue = $b['amount'];

    // Sort in descending order
    return $bValue <=> $aValue;
});

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
```